# Cannot vertical aling all element inside a div (1 image 2 span) the 2 span should be in top of each other

Tags: html, css

Hello i have tried for days in vain to create a block of items in HTML 5 and CSS in which there is an div that contains an image on the left, 2 text next to the image which should be one in top of the other when on mobile view but responsive so that in the normal browser view they should be on a single line.

I have tried to combine several css solutions from SO with partial success, and as far as I reach this is the most I was able to achieve

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  /*not support gradient browsers*/
  background: #002053;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10 auto;
}

.selected-element {
  height:9rem;
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #ccc;
}

.saved-users {
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.3);
}

.segment {
  line-height: 3.5rem;
}

.icon {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
  vertical-align:
}

.user-elements {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css">

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main class="container">
      <section class="saved-users">
        <div class="selected-element" id="freaking-id">
          <img src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/12096062?v=4" class="icon">
          <span class="segment">
            <span class="user-elements user-name"> Username </span>
            <span class="user-elements time-stamp">2018-10-05 22:49:41</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="selected-element" id="second-id">
          <img src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/12096062?v=4" class="icon segment">
          <span class="segment"> 
            <span class="user-elements user-name"> Second Username </span>
            <span class="user-elements time-stamp">2018-10-07 22:09:41</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CSS media query for changing your style on mobile view.
You can check this demo:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  /*not support gradient browsers*/
  background: #002053;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10 auto;
}

.selected-element {
  height:9rem;
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #ccc;
  line-height: 9rem;
}

.saved-users {
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.3);
}

.segment {
  line-height: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.user-elements {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

/* Mobile Layout: 320px. */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.segment {
    max-width: 80%;
    line-height: 3rem;
}
.user-elements {
    display: block;
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css">
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main class="container">
      <section class="saved-users">
        <div class="selected-element" id="freaking-id">
          <img src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/12096062?v=4" class="icon">
          <span class="segment">
            <span class="user-elements user-name"> Username </span>
            <span class="user-elements time-stamp">2018-10-05 22:49:41</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="selected-element" id="second-id">
          <img src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/12096062?v=4" class="icon segment">
          <span class="segment"> 
            <span class="user-elements user-name"> Second Username </span>
            <span class="user-elements time-stamp">2018-10-07 22:09:41</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip...It works as expected now, still I am not sure on how did you achieve to put the to span one in top of the other...I still feel a bit confused regarding regular css ^^"

Comment: You just need to make it block when you want the span in a single line.